# Hover effect on button not working - CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Below is my HTML/CSS code in which I am trying to create a similar effect like HOME button as mentioned here - https://codepen.io/larrygeams/pen/pdchG

I made it to a single class, but my code is not working. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```css
.btn-primary {
  background: green;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-primary:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn-primary:after:hover {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-primary" type="submit">
    <div class="inner">Add to bag</div>
</button>
```

My Non Working Codepen Link - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gBdVoj?editors=1100

Comment: Side note, button elements can't have div elements as children

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want an animated hover? If so, you are missing a few attributes (position: relative, overflow, z-index). Check out my codepen and the css changes (marked with `/* ADDED */` and `/* CHANGED */`). Hope this helps
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJJWyQ?editors=1100

Comment: @elveti thx alot...this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hover` pseudo needs to be placed **before** `::after`

`:hover::after`

```css
.btn-primary {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 2;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.btn-primary::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn-primary:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-primary" type="submit">Add to bag</button>
```

Comment: Your hover effect is on background and not inside button.

Comment: @Nesh see changes above. Is this what you want?